# Liferay 6.1.1 - ORA-00904: "IMAGEIMPL0_"."TEXT_": invalid identifier

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I am using liferay 6.1.1 with tomcat 7. It boots fine till login page. Once I click on login, it throws the error "ORA-00904: "IMAGEIMPL0_"."TEXT_"invalid identifier.

Has anyone any idea what this is and why this is coming.  The entries in DB look fine (Image attached).

The same issue has been reported at : https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/58226128

[DB-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKtA8.png).

Comment: The screenshot seems to be unrelated. It looks like the screenshot of the release_ table. imageimpl0_ might rather be the Image Table. Can you verify that Image.TEXT_ exisits?

Comment: thanks @andre. Indeed the issue was TEXT_

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still facing this issue, the problem was that somehow the TEXT_ column was removed from the Image Table. Simply adding the column resolved the issue for me